# std::getline with char* to strings

Tags: c++

I have this code for reading from a file:

```
MyObject* LoadObject(wstring filePath)
{
    ifstream fileReader;
    fileReader.open(filePath);
    if (fileReader.is_open())
    {
        string currentLine;
        //std::basic_istream &std::getline
        while (getline(fileReader, currentLine))
        {
            //Logic for loading MyObject* here
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to read from a char* buffer as well, is there a way I can keep the same reading logic and just changing how I read the lines?

```
MyObject* LoadObject(char* buffer, ulong length)
{
    //Change how I read each line

    //Keep the same logic for loading MyObject*
}
```

Comment: The first `LoadObject()` specifies a file path.  What is the second one supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your work into something that takes a `std::istream &` to read from:

```
MyObject *ReadObject(std::istream &is) 
{
    string currentLine;
    while (getline(is, currentLine))
    {
        //Logic for loading MyObject* here
    }
}
```

Now just make your other functions use this one:

```
MyObject* LoadObject(wstring filePath)
{
    ifstream fileReader;
    fileReader.open(filePath);
    if (fileReader.is_open())
    {
        return ReadObject(fileReader);
    }
    ... //return something else
}

MyObject* LoadObject(char* buffer, ulong length)
{
    std::string str(buffer, length);
    std::istringsteam iss(str);
    return ReadObject(iss);
}
```

Some small notes:

- Pass `filePath` by const reference since you're not changing it and don't need a copy.
- Make `buffer` a `const char *` if it's a C string, since you don't need to modify it. Better to use one parameter that knows the length instead of relying on the caller to synchronize the two parameters.
- Consider returning a `MyObject` by value unless you really need the pointer.
- Consider naming the two overloads of `LoadObject` differently to convey their intent. For all the caller knows, the C string overload could be a file path as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it would perform well, but you can do something like this:

```
std::istringstream iss(std::string(buffer, length));
while (getline(iss, currentLine))
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your existing method and take actual reading code into separate method:

```
MyObject* LoadObjectFromStream(std::istream &in)
{
    string currentLine;
    //std::basic_istream &std::getline
    while (getline(fileReader, currentLine))
    {
         //Logic for loading MyObject* here
    }
}
```

Then use this method in both variants:

```
MyObject* LoadObject(wstring filePath)
{
    ifstream fileReader;
    fileReader.open(filePath);
    if (fileReader.is_open())
        return loadObjectFromStream( fileReader );
}

MyObject* LoadObject(const char *buffer, size_t size )
{
    istrstream stream( buffer, size );
    return loadObjectFromStream( stream );
}
```

you may want to make `LoadObjectFromStream` private etc, but that details of implementation.